# Google map and markers choosable by html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Markers at map doesnt show. What's wrong?

http://pastebin.com/VYbZVF7H

After it. I want to make choosable marker [option] in [datalist] [html5].

http://pastebin.com/mgjEvG7A

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your script is that you are putting your ***markers*** in an ***array***, but it ***does not exist*** (check your console, *marker is undefined*). 
Just declare `var marker = [];`, call `getMarkers()` function and your code will run just fine.

Comment: There is /var locations/ [array]... I guess it's problem with function getMarkers() but don't know where is it...

Comment: The only problem I've seen is that you never even call the function.